# css animation fires only when element loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I´ve got a dropdown field where the user can change values via ajax. When the change-event occurs and the data is saved in the database, the user gets a visual "success-feedback" by making the row which contains the dropdownfield glow green.
This works fine so far, but the glow animation (css) fires only if the row loses focus / if i hover out of the row with the mouse (no need to click). I would appreciate any advices; maybe the whole concept of how i´m doing this glow is wrong (putting it in "success" in the ajax-call).

javascript:

```
$("[name='dropdown_status']").on('change', function() {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var bestell_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/files/ajax/wm_change_status_dt.php',
                data: {
                    id_bestell: bestell_id,
                    id_status: $(this).val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    tr.addClass('dropdown_anim');
                    tr.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
                        tr.removeClass('dropdown_anim');
                    });
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
                    alert(status + ': ' + err);
                }
            });
        }
```

css:

```
.dropdown_anim {
  background: transparent;
  animation: color-me-in 1s;
}

@keyframes color-me-in {
 0% {
    background: transparent;
  }
  /* Adding a step in the middle */
  50% {
    background: #D3FCC7;
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you replicate issue on jsFiddle? Is that same issue on all major browsers or just specific to one? Maybe you need to force UI redraw. To test it, you could try: `tr.addClass('dropdown_anim').hide().show(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Please try following syntax (and add dropdown element id `dropdown_status`)

```
$(document).on("change", "#dropdown_status", function() {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var bestell_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/files/ajax/wm_change_status_dt.php',
                data: {
                    id_bestell: bestell_id,
                    id_status: $(this).val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    tr.addClass('dropdown_anim');
                    tr.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
                        tr.removeClass('dropdown_anim');
                    });
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
                    alert(status + ': ' + err);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried what you suggested, and it`s still the same problem :-(

Comment: you have `tr.one` instead of `tr.on` - additional clue ;)

Comment: ooops, sorry then ;)

Comment: "[...]The .one() method is identical to .on(), except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation[...]" from http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it:
turned out, everything worked as it should. The only problem was css code, that was fired when the tablerow is hovered (changing it´s background-color). So, the green glow effect was not visible, or was only visible as soon as the row lost focus.